# switching from MySQL to PostgreSQL for Ruby on Rails for the sake of Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to push a brand new Ruby on Rails app to Heroku. Currently, it sits on MySQL. It looks like Heroku doesn't really support MySQL and so we are considering using PostgreSQL, which they DO support.

How difficult should I expect this to be? What do I need to do to make this happen?

Again, please note that my DB as of right now (both development & production) are completely empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't feel you have to migrate to Postgres - there are several MySQL Addon providers available  on Heroku - http://addons.heroku.com/cleardb is the one I've had the most success with.

Comment: cool I may have to go ahead and try this out, thanks for the info!

Comment: It should be noted that the MySQL addon has limitations that make it not practical for serious applications.

Answer (score 11):

Common issues:

1. GROUP BY behavior. PostgreSQL has a rather strict GROUP BY. If you use a GROUP BY clause, then every column in your SELECT must either appear in your GROUP BY or be used in an aggregate function.
2. Data truncation. MySQL will quietly truncate a long string to fit inside a `char(n)` column unless your server is in strict mode, PostgreSQL will complain and make you truncate your string yourself.
3. Quoting is different, MySQL uses backticks for quoting identifiers whereas PostgreSQL uses double quotes.
4. LIKE is case insensitive in MySQL but not in PostgreSQL. This leads many MySQL users to use LIKE as a case insensitive string equality operator.

(1) will be an issue if you use AR's `group` method in any of your queries or GROUP BY in any raw SQL. Do some searching for `column "X" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` and you'll see some examples and common solutions.

(2) will be an issue if you use string columns anywhere in your application and your models aren't properly validating the length of **all** incoming string values. Note that creating a string column in Rails without specifying a limit actually creates a `varchar(255)` column so there actually is an implicit `:limit => 255` even though you didn't specify one. An alternative is to use `t.text` for your strings instead of `t.string`; this will let you work with arbitrarily large strings without penalty (for PostgreSQL at least). As Erwin notes below (and every other chance he gets), `varchar(n)` is a bit of an anachronism in the PostgreSQL world.

(3) shouldn't be a problem unless you have raw SQL in your code.

(4) will be an issue if you're using LIKE anywhere in your application. You can fix this one by changing `a like b` to `lower(a) like lower(b)` (or `upper(a) like upper(b)` if you like to shout) or `a ilike b` but be aware that [PostgreSQL's ILIKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) is non-standard.

There are other differences that can cause trouble but those seem like the most common issues.

You'll have to review a few things to feel safe:

- `group` calls.
- Raw SQL (including any snippets in `where` calls).
- String length validations in your models.
- All uses of LIKE.

Comment: Ad 1. GROUP BY: this is true for version 8.3 (Heroku), but has changed in version 9.1. [Release notes tell us](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/release-9-1.html): `Allow non-GROUP BY columns in the query target list when the primary key is specified in the GROUP BY clause (Peter Eisentraut)`

Comment: Ad 2. You can avoid all troubles by using the superior string data type `text` in PostgreSQL (or `varchar` without length specifier). **If** you have `varchar(n)` columns, you can avoid errors by casting explicitely: `'foobarbaz'::varchar(3)`. I quote the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/datatype-character.html): `over-length will be truncated to n characters without raising an error.`

Comment: @Erwin: Heroku uses 8.3 for shared, 9.0 for dedicated so the GROUP BY issue still applies until Heroku gets around to upgrading (I've been hoping for a 9.1 upgrade just to get Peter's GROUP BY change). And you're stuck with the varchar issues when using Rails unless you use `text` instead of `string` for your columns (those are the Rails types, not the PostgreSQL ones), you also won't be able to get casts into the SQL unless you write it all by hand and that's just not going to happen in Rails code.

Comment: @Erwin: I added some notes about string vs text as that is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no data to migrate, it should be as simple as telling your `Gemfile` to use the `pg` gem instead, running `bundle install`, and updating your `database.yml` file to point to your PostgreSQL databases. Then just run your migrations (`rake db:migrate`) and everything should work great.

Answer (score 0):

It should be simplicity itself: port the DDL from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

Does Heroku have any schema creation scripts?  I'd depend on those if they were available.

MySQL and PostgreSQL are different (e.g. identity type for MySQL, sequences for PostgreSQL).  But the port shouldn't be too hard.  How many tables?  Tens are doable.