# How much of an effort is it to migrate from Amazon RDS (MySql) to Heroku Postgres?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, amazon-rds

One of our production apps has been on Amazon RDS (MySql) for a few months now. I must say, all is well. Except for the fact that Amazon RDS does periodic backups of the db, causing a temporary downtime (few minutes).

I did some reading, and found out that having the [Multi-AZ setup](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/#Multi-AZ) will prevent this. However, this setup will increase the costs by 2x! Which is almost the equivalent to a dedicated db plan at Heroku.

Anyone from experience. Is such a move beneficial? Should I just stick with my MySql setup? We currently have 3 months of production data.

For the ones that have migrated over to Postgres from MySql. Was the effort in doing so long and tedious?

Comment: Do you use GROUP BY in your SQL? How much raw SQL do you have? How strict are your length validations before you insert/update `varchar` columns? Do you use a framework of some sort that writes your SQL? If yes, which one? Do you assume that LIKE is case insensitive? This could be a cakewalk or it could be a nightmare

Comment: I use Ruby on Rails 3x, which uses ActiveRecord. GROUP BY = yes. Length validations in our app are handled on the application layer, not the db layer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [switching from MySQL to PostgreSQL for Ruby on Rails for the sake of Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736041/switching-from-mysql-to-postgresql-for-ruby-on-rails-for-the-sake-of-heroku) or perhaps close enough that the answers would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of this article: http://blog.sendhub.com/switching-to-heroku-a-django-app-story (dead link, see mirrors: [#1](https://web.archive.org/web/20120202201233/http://blog.sendhub.com/post/16800984141/switching-to-heroku-a-django-app-story), [#2](https://archive.is/mBckE))

It's Django related but there's a section on migrating from MySQL to Postgres which is relevant to you.